# REGEX Build for a sequence

Tags: php, regex, validation

I want to do the validation for the String "DDP-FA12-BSE-007" using regex. Any help will be appreciated :) 
tHE string is `ABC-DE12-FGH-345` or `DE12-FGH-345`

1. In first 3 places all the alphabets are Allowed.
2. Then a -
3. 2nd place consist of two parts. For first two places only alphabets.
   While for last two places only Digits are allowed.
4. Then a -
5. On 3rd place only two Alphabets are allowed.
6. Then a -
7. For forth place there should be only three Digits are allowed.

It should be like this `DDP-FA12-BSE-007` or `FA12-BSE-007`

Ps: `DE` Should be `FA`or `SP`

Comment: Only for this string ?

Comment: What is the pattern? What have you tired?

Comment: tHE string is `ABC-DE12-FGH-345`

Comment: Yes, I read that in the question, `the String "DDP-FA12-BSE-007"`. You could simple do a `==` if that is the only thing you want to match.

Comment: @chris85 please check the updated Question. I hope it will be appreciating

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Answer is

`^[A-Za-z]{3}-[A-Za-z]{2}\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{3}|^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{3}$`

It will help to DO the verification for Upper an lowercase letters as well as
`DDP-FA12-BSE-007` Or `FA12-BSE-007`

For online check this link 
`https://regex101.com/r/mJ9dH4/2`

Comment: Nope, I posted an answer, it meet your specifications you accepted it. You then changed your specs and unaccepted. This is an XY problem, meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-proble‌​m. I'll leave you with this though, https://regex101.com/r/mJ9dH4/3.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
^[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{2}\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{3}$
```

For little bit changes by yourself so must visit [Regerx](http://regexr.com/). So here you can see cheat code and it is very easy to develop regex by yourself. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you For the answer

Comment: @SyedNoman OP can't upvote and only one answer can be accepted. If the answer had a description, I'd upvote; or if the `Regerx` linked to a functional demo.